# Pass list of functions to `microbenchmark` to be evaluated

Tags: r, microbenchmark

I have a directory of files called `dir`.

I would like to run a function called `f(file, arg1, arg2)` on each of the files in `dir`.

I want to benchmark each of these functions against each other in `microbenchmark`.

How can I create a list of functions called `funcs` to be evaluated that looks like:

```
$a
f("file1", arg1, arg2)

$b
f("file2", arg1, arg2)

$c
f("file3", arg1, arg2)
```

So that I can simply call `microbenchmark::microbenchmark(funcs)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a list of unevaluated expressions. One way to do that is to `lapply` parameters to `bquote` to build those expressions. Then be sure to bast that list to the `list=` parameter of `microbenchmark()`. For example

```
tests <- lapply(paste0("file", 1:3), function(x) {
  bquote(f(.(x), arg1, arg2))
})
microbenchmark(list=tests)
```

Here's a reproducible example

```
tests <- lapply(c(1,10,100), function(x) {
  bquote(rnorm(.(x)))
})
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(list=tests)
# Unit: microseconds
#        expr min  lq  mean median  uq  max neval cld
#    rnorm(1) 1.4 1.5 1.783    1.6 1.7 15.5   100 a  
#   rnorm(10) 1.9 2.1 2.253    2.2 2.3  4.0   100  b 
#  rnorm(100) 7.8 8.1 8.741    8.5 9.0 12.7   100   c
```